# Styling output in ternary operator

Tags: php

how to put color the in output of ternary operator.

I would like to do if false it should be black if true it should be red

this is my code:

```
'<td>' .($totalStocks < $minimumStockLevel ? 'true': 'false'). '</td>' .
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Hideous old approach could be`'<font color="#f00">true</font>'`

Comment: I didnt try that, I only tried this one <style="color:red;">true</style>. I will try your suggestion thank you.

Comment: `style` is not an element, you could use `style` as an attribute of `span` or `p`, etc.

Comment: I did try that and it works thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need some CSS, and then add an appropriate class to your data:

```
<style>
  .redCell {color:red;}
  .blackCell {color:black;}
</style>
```

Then your code becomes:

```
'<td class="'.($totalStocks < $minimumStockLevel ? 'redCell': 'blackCell').'">' .$someValue. '</td>' .
```

This should generate something like this:

```
<td class="redCell">someValue</td>
```

Comment: With this approach 2 ternarys would be required.

Comment: If you do it exactly this way, perhaps. You could structure your ternary to emit the entire `<td>` cell, including class and cell contents. Using CSS classes is the correct way to do this. Using `<font>` elements may well become unsupported in time.

Comment: Any block element, or even inline would work with `style` attribute. If class/id is used you need ternary for class assignment, and then one for value output.